# Setting an array as an input parameter for a method

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters, double

How would I write a method that takes an array of the double data type as input. What variables would I need to declare?

Comment: "How would I write a method that takes an array of the double data type as input." -- I would suggest using a keyboard.  "What variables would I need to declare?" -- none.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class FirstJavaClass {
    public void method(double[] input) {
        // ... do something amazing with it!
    }
}
```